# Transfer theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-combinatorics

I want to solve the following problem:

Determine the coefficients 
$$[x^n] \frac{1}{1-\sin(\pi x)}$$
up to a multiplicative error of $1+ O(n^{-1})$. In other words, find a function $f(n)$ so that 
$$[x^n]\frac{1}{1-\sin(\pi x)} = f(n)(1 + O(n^{-1}).$$

From my lecture notes I have the following transfer theorem:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z_{\leq 0}}$ and assume $f(z)$ is $\Delta$-analytic at 1. Then, if $f(z) = (1-z)^{-\alpha} + o((1-z)^{-\alpha})$
$$ [z^n] f(z) = \frac{n^{\alpha -1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} ( 1+ O(\frac{1}{n})) + o (n^{\alpha - 1})$$

Now to get $\frac{1}{1- \sin(\pi x)}$ in a form to apply the above theorem, I tried to use Taylor expansion around $x= \frac{1}{2}$ but I do not get the wanted terms.

Can I apply the above theorem for this problem or do I have to solve this problem differently?

Comment: Why not use $x=0$ instead?

Comment: In other examples, Taylor expansion was applied at singularity points, so i used $x = 1/2$. Using $x=0$ I get $1 + \pi x + \pi^2 x^2 + (5 \pi^3 x^3)/6$, which has no negative power terms.